# how can I 'crash proof' a callback function written in C if passed the wrong parameter type

Tags: c, pointers, types, signals

I have a callback function written in C that runs on a server and MUST be crash proof. That is, if expecting an integer and is passed a character string pointer, I must internal to the function determine that, and prevent getting Segmentation faults when trying to do something not allowed on the incorrect parameter type.

The function protoype is:

```
void callback_function(parameter_type a, const b);
```

and 'a' is supposed to tell me, via enum, whether 'b' is an integer or a character string pointer.
If the calling function programmer makes a mistake, and tells me in 'a' that 'b' is an integer, and 'b' is really a character string pointer, then how do I determine that without crashing the callback function code. This runs on a server and must keep going if the caller function made a mistake.

The code has to be in C, and be portable so C library extensions would not be possible. The compiler is: gcc v4.8.2
The sizeof an integer on the platform is 4, and so is the length of a character pointer.
An integer could have the same value, numerically, as a character pointer, and vice versa.

If I think I get a character pointer and its not, when I try to find the content of that, I of course get a Segmentation Fault.

If I write a signal handler to handle the fault, how do I now "clear" the signal, and resume execution at a sane place?

Did I mention that 'b' is a union defined as:

```
union param_2 {
  char * c;
  int i;
} param_to_be_passed;
```

I think that's about it.

Thank You for your answers.

Comment: Are there any practical bounds on what the integer input could be?  I'd perform some rationalization test on how 'integery' or how 'pointery' the input is.  Also, are there any practical bounds on how long the string is?  I'd look into that too.  I'd don't think you can 100% prevent a crash, but you should be able to come close.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible.

There's no way to "look" at at pointer and determine if it's valid to de-reference, except for `NULL`-checking it of course.

Other than that, there's no magic way to know if a pointer points at character data, an integer, a function, or anything else.

Comment: There are some POSIX hacks to do it. I think I've seen calling `write` with a pointer and size of 0, or maybe size 1. The kernel will check the memory location for read access and return `EFAULT`.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a hack.

What ever proposal comes, do not use such things in production.

If late binding is needed take a different, a fail-safe approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing code for an embedded device, you would expect that all variables would reside in RAM.  For example, you might have 128 kB of RAM from addresses `0x20000000` to `0x20020000`.  If you were passed a pointer to a memory address without this range, in regard to `c`, that would be another way to determine something was wrong, in addition to checking for a NULL address.

```
if((a == STRING) && ((b.c == NULL) || (b.c < 0x20000000) || (b.c > 0x20020000)))
    return ERROR;
```

If you're working in a multithreaded environment, you may be able to take this a step further and require all addresses passed to `callback_function` come from a certain thread's memory space (stack).

Answer (score 0):

Run-time type checking in C is effectively impossible.

The burden is on the caller to pass the data correctly; there's no (good, standard, portable) way for you to determine whether `b` contains data of the correct type (that is, that the caller didn't pass you a pointer value as an integer or vice versa).

The only suggestion I can make is to create two separate callbacks, one of which takes an `int` and the other a `char *`, and put the burden on the compiler to do type checking at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This doesn't actually attempt to make the function "crash-proof", because I suspect that thats not possible.

If you are allowed to change the API, one option may be to combine the union only use an api for accessing the type.

```
typedef enum Type { STRING, INT } Type;
typedef struct StringOrInt {
    Type type;
    union { int i; char* s } value;
} StringOrInt;

void soi_set_int(StringOrInt* v, int i) {
     v->type = INT;
     v->value.i = i;
}

void soi_set_string(StringOrInt* v, char* s) {
     v->type = STRING;
     v->value.s = s;
}

Type soi_get_type(StringOrInt cosnt* v) {
     return v->type;
}

int soi_get_int(StringOrInt const* v) {
     assert(v->type == INT);
     return v->value.i;
}

char* soi_get_string(StringOrInt const* v) {
     assert(v->type == STRING);
     return v->value.s;
}
```

While this doesn't actually make it crash proof, users of the API will find it more convenient to use the API than change the members by hand, reducing the errors significantly.

Answer (score 0):

If the caller says in `a` that the result is `int`, there is no great risk of crash, because:

- in your case both types have the same length (be aware that this is NOT GUARANTEED TO BE PORTABLE!)
- The C standards says (ISO - sect.6.3.2.3): "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined.
- But fortunately, most 32 bit values will be a valid integer.

Keep in mind that in the worst case, the value could be meaningless. So you it's up to you to avoid the crash, by systematically verifying consistency of the value (for example do bound controls if you use the integer to adress some array elements)

If the caller says in "a" that the result is a pointer but provides an int, it's much more difficult to avoid a crash in a portable manner.

- The standard ISO says: An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
- In practice most of these errors are trapped by memory access exceptions at a very low system level. The behaviour being implementation defined, there's no portable way of doing it.